# Find Probabilty of ~Fever

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I have been given this

```
P(Strep(some infection)) = 0.15    

P(fever|strep) = 0.6    

P(fever|~strep) = 0.3
```

Find P(strep|fever)
I could find this put by using bases rule.
Bayes rule is
`P(A/B) = P(B/A)*P(A) / P(B)`

Here B is fever.

How do I find P(fever)?

Is it sum of `P(fever|strep) and this P(fever|~strep)`

If I can do this, and find P(~fever), I get it more than 1.

Where am I wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is found as follows:

$$
P(\text{fever}) = P(\text{fever} \mid \text{strep}) P(\text{strep})
                + P(\text{fever} \mid \neg\text{strep}) P(\neg\text{strep})
$$

where $\neg$ is the negation operator (I'm assuming that's what $\sim$ is in your question).

Comment: Will the formula remain same if I want to find P(~fever). Is it Marginalization ? Thank you

Comment: Yes, with the suitable replacement of fever by $\neg$fever.